# Recursive SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion

my SQLite database is kinda like this:

| startn | rel | endn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| immunodeficiencies | includes | B-cell deficiencies |
| B-cell deficiencies | includes | Bruton agammaglobulinemia |
| immunodeficiencies | includes | T-cell deficiencies |
| T-cell deficiencies | includes | DiGeorge syndrome |

There's a lot more values, but that's the gist.

I'm trying to make a recursive query that gets all the terminal child nodes of `immunodeficiencies`. Ie, for this example I'd like `Bruton agammaglobulinemia, DiGeorge syndrome`

Based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549225/is-it-possible-to-write-a-sqlite-query-which-recursively-gets-all-items-that-are), here's what I have so far, but it's not working:

```
with recursive tc( i )
  as ( select endn from dx_graph where startn = 'immunodeficiencies' and rel = 'includes'
        union endn from dx_graph, tc where startn = tc.i and rel = 'includes'
     )
 select * from tc;
```

sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE "dx_graph" (
    "startn"    TEXT,
    "rel"   TEXT,
    "endn"  TEXT,
)

insert into dx_graph values ('immunodeficiencies', 'includes', 'B-cell deficiencies')
insert into dx_graph values ('immunodeficiencies', 'includes', 'T-cell deficiencies')
insert into dx_graph values ('immunodeficiencies', 'includes', 'complement disorders')
insert into dx_graph values ('B-cell deficiencies', 'includes', 'Bruton agammaglobulinemia')
insert into dx_graph values ('T-cell deficiencies', 'includes', 'DiGeorge syndrome')
insert into dx_graph values ('complement disorders', 'includes', 'C1 esterase inhibitor deficiency')
insert into dx_graph values ('complement disorders', 'includes', 'C5-C9 deficiency')
```

Comment: I know that what I really want is a graph database, but honestly I tried Neo4J and it's inserting new values was just super clunky.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "child node".  Desired results would help.

Comment: Just added it, thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data as plain text, preferably a create table and insert statements for easy importing into a test database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive query will find all child nodes of the original specified parent; you then need to filter them based on whether they have any child nodes or not. You can do this with a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tc AS (
  SELECT endn
  FROM dx_graph 
  WHERE startn = 'immunodeficiencies' AND rel = 'includes'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dx.endn
  FROM dx_graph dx
  JOIN tc ON dx.startn = tc.endn AND dx.rel = 'includes'
)
SELECT endn
FROM tc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM dx_graph dx
  WHERE dx.startn = tc.endn AND dx.rel = 'includes'
)
```

Output (for sample data in question):

```
endn
Bruton agammaglobulinemia
DiGeorge syndrome
C1 esterase inhibitor deficiency
C5-C9 deficiency
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/85FibmxXryHyViQeBo8DmB/3)

The `NOT EXISTS` clause filters out any nodes from the recursive CTE that have a child node (i.e. the `endn` value from the CTE matches a `startn` value in the original table that has a `rel='includes'`). That way you only get the terminal nodes, as they have no children.