# Tables for recursive hierarchial data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to do a recursive self-join in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757260/simplest-way-to-do-a-recursive-self-join-in-sql-server)

I have to create a table in SQL that will comprise of groups of items/products. Each new group made will be made under one of the **pre-defined** groups or the groups previously formed. I want to keep all this data in a SQL Table. So far, I have though of creating a table like this:

- Group ID
- Group Name
- Group Under (This will store the ID of the group under which this group is from

But this can only refer to just the next level, how will I get to know who is the super-parent of this group.

For example:

- I have groups `A, B, C`.
- `A` has further subgroups `A1, A2, A3`.
- `A1` has further subgroups, `A11, A12, A13`.

I will I have the information about super-parent group i.e `A` from `A11` or `A22` or `A33`?

Let me know if the problem is not clear..

Comment: I don't need to have a join. I want to know which is the top level group in the chain for a particular group.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal: You **do** need a JOIN. You need to recursively JOIN the Group table to itself, climbing the hierarchy of groups until `GroupUnder` is `NULL`. When it is `NULL`, you know that the `GroupID` in that row is the top level group. The post to which I linked does exactly that. This is not a trivial problem to solve. The solution may look daunting at first but really it's quite elegant.

Comment: @Cory I am really thankful to you, but to be very honest, I am not getting it at all, maybe because I am new to this. I have to set up tax rates to top level groups, like 10% for A and 15 % to B. Now when I encounter a group called A12, I move up the hierarchy, and I reach A1 which I find is NOT a top level group! I again move up by one level and I find that I have reached A, which IS a top level group, I just fetch the tax rate from there and apply it to further calculations in my coding.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008, C# for the programming, and VS 2010 as the IDE.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal: See my answer below. I realize it's a bit contrived, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming T-SQL and MSSQLServer (you didn't specify), and given that your `Group` table should look something like this:

```
Id | Name | ParentId
---+------+---------
 1 | A    | NULL
 2 | B    | NULL
 3 | C    | NULL
 4 | A1   | 1
 5 | A2   | 1
 6 | A3   | 1
 7 | A11  | 4
 8 | A12  | 4
 9 | A13  | 4
```

You can use the following recursive CTE to find the top level a given group, say 'A12':

```
WITH [Group](Id, Name, ParentId) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'A'  , NULL UNION
    SELECT 2, 'B'  , NULL UNION
    SELECT 3, 'C'  , NULL UNION
    SELECT 4, 'A1' , 1    UNION
    SELECT 5, 'A2' , 1    UNION
    SELECT 6, 'A3' , 1    UNION
    SELECT 7, 'A11', 4    UNION
    SELECT 8, 'A12', 4    UNION
    SELECT 9, 'A13', 4

), q AS 
(
    SELECT  
        *
    FROM    
        [Group]
    WHERE
        [Name] = 'A12' -- Given 'A12' as the child
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  
        g.*
    FROM
        [Group] g
    JOIN    
        q
        ON      
        q.ParentId = g.Id
    )
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    q
WHERE
    ParentId IS NULL
```

This query returns:

```
Id | Name | ParentId
---+------+---------
 1 | A    | NULL
```

Comment: Can you please explain the statements a little so that I can adjust them in my _SQLDATAADAPTER_ query? I am unable to understand a few things.