# Getting lowest level in a tree from any higher level with a self-join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using sql server 2012, I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Type | Code  | Parent_Type | Parent_Code
  4  | 123   |     2       |     1
  4  | 234   |     2       |     1
  6  | 1234  |     4       |     123 
  6  | 2345  |     4       |     234
  7  | 12345 |     6       |     1234
  7  | 23456 |     6       |     1234
  7  | 34567 |     6       |     2345
```

It maps parent type/code combinations to child type/code combinations. It maps type 2 to type 4, 4 to type 6 and 6 to type 7. If I look for all the records with a `Parent_Type` of `2` and a `Parent_Code` of `1`:

```
select * from mytable where parent_type = 2 and parent_code = 1
```

It will return:

```
Type | Code  | Parent_Type | Parent_Code
  4  | 123   |     2       |     1
  4  | 234   |     2       |     1
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out the best way to get all of the type 7 codes that live under the ultimate parent type 1 code. In addition, I need this to work for any type level. So I'd like to be able to get the type 7 codes under a type 4 code, or even with a type 7 code (which just returns the single matching row).

So what I'd like to see, when searching for `parent_type = 2 and parent_code = 1` is:

```
Type | Code  | Parent_Type | Parent_Code
  7  | 12345 |     6       |     1234
  7  | 23456 |     6       |     1234
  7  | 34567 |     6       |     2345
```

But if I'd started at  `parent_type = 4 and parent_code = 123`

```
Type | Code  | Parent_Type | Parent_Code
  7  | 12345 |     6       |     1234
  7  | 23456 |     6       |     1234
```

I initially tried this:

```
select grandchild.type
       grandchild.code
       parent.parent_type
       parent.parent_code
from mytable as parent
join mytable as child on parent.code = child.parent_code
join mytable as grandchild on child.code = grandchild.parent_code
where parent.parent.code = 1
```

Which works great if you start with a type 2 code, but fails (returns no results) at any other level.

So I search about a bit and came on this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757302/1250301

And tried this:

```
with q as
(
    select * 
    from mytable
    where parent_type = 2
    union all
    select m.*
    from mytable m
    join q
    on m.parent_code = q.code
)
Select *
from q where parent_code = 1
```

But still only works on one level returning the same result as my initial `select` query.

How can I get this to select all the level 7 codes starting with any higher level code?

Note, my ultimate goal is to join this result with another table of type/code combinations (with potentially mixed types) to convert it to a list of all level 7 codes (which then gets joined with another table that has the data I need, but only at the level 7 code level).

Comment: I kinda got lost in the word problem. Can you post a sample of the desired result for a sample input?

Comment: @Lamak: Ok - tried to make it a little clearly with a couple of expected outputs start from two different points.

Comment: Have you had a look at HierarchyId, specifically adjacency list pattern?

Comment: Why do you have `where parent_type = 2` in your code?

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks, it clarified the question a lot for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
DECLARE @parent_type INT, @parent_code INT
SET @parent_type = 2
SET @parent_code = 1;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE (parent_type = @parent_type AND parent_code = @parent_code) OR (type = @parent_type AND code = @parent_code)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.*
    FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN YourTable B
        ON A.Code = B.Parent_Code
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Type = 7;
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49c19/2) with a demo of this.

The results for `parent_type = 2` and `parent_code = 1` are:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Type ║ Code  ║ Parent_Type ║ Parent_Code ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║    7 ║ 34567 ║           6 ║        2345 ║
║    7 ║ 12345 ║           6 ║        1234 ║
║    7 ║ 23456 ║           6 ║        1234 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

And for `parent_type = 4` and `parent_code = 123`:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ Type ║ Code  ║ Parent_Type ║ Parent_Code ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║    7 ║ 12345 ║           6 ║        1234 ║
║    7 ║ 23456 ║           6 ║        1234 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Thanks. That actually works great with one exception (and maybe I should have highlighted this in the question a bit better). If you start with a `type = 7` code, it'll return no results. I would like it to return just the one matching result. But I can probably figure that out myself or else work around it.

Comment: Ok - I edited to add an `or` in the `where` clause to fix the `type=7` issue. Hope you don't mind.