# Collect All Children of a parent from given table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

I want to collect all child rows with a given parent from this table in TSQL.

```
ID     Name   parentID
------ ------ ---------
 1     ABCD          0
 2     xyz           1
 3     efg           1
 4     lm            2
```

Please let me know how can get in hierarchy list using linq.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1757302/2811743

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Make and AJAX call from the client to your static method:**

```
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/WebMethods/Test.aspx/getChildren",
              data: "{myID:" + someID+ "}",
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (msg) {
                  // work on your json

              },
              error: function (msg) {
                  alert("error:" + JSON.stringify(msg));
              }
          });
```

Find your parent entity using a parameter, then you can find all children entities that belong to that parent. Make sure your foreign key constraints are established in your entity model.

```
       public static string getChildren(int myID){
                using (var rep = new context()) {
                Header head = rep.Headers.Where(x => x.ID== myID).First();

                var details = head.Details.ToList();
                }
       // Convert List to JSON and return to client
                string myChidren="";
                return myChildren;
       }
```

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates ASP.Net is involved, or that "client side" means a browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example for your case.

```
using (DbContext context = new DbContext())
{
    List<Collect> lstObj = context.Collect.OrderBy(c=> c.ID).ToList();
}
```