# SQL Recursive Query on hirachical name

Tags: sql, recursive-query

New to MS SQL. 
Having the table like as follows,

```
ID  Name    Parent ID
1   AA      0
2   BB      1
3   CC      2
4   DD      3
5   EE      3
6   FF      4
7   FG      6
8   AD      1
9   AC      2
```

My expected Result is showed in the Hierarchical Name

```
ID  Name    Parent ID   Hirarchical Name
1   AA      0           AA
2   BB      1           AA.BB
3   CC      2           AA.BB.CC
4   DD      3           AA.BB.CC.DD
5   EE      3           AA.BB.CC.EE
6   FF      4           AA.BB.CC.DD.FF
7   FG      6           AA.BB.CC.DD.FF.FG
8   AD      1           AA.AD
9   AC      2           AA.BB.AC
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried with inner join and union all.. but its not giving me the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to do a recursive self-join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757260/simplest-way-to-do-a-recursive-self-join)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTEs are a bit tricky.  This does what you want:

```
with cte as (
      select id, name, convert(varchar(max), name) as hier, 1 as lev
      from t
      where parentid = 0
      union all
      select t.id, t.name, cte.hier + '.' + t.name, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on t.parentid = cte.id
      where lev < 10
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc5999a24eb139cc7908c853ecb61ca9) is a db<>fiddle.