# SQL - left join table to itself

Tags: sql, join

In short, want to left join table to itself, but only rows that have id 1 or 2

Table:

```
id f1
1  a
1  b 
2  a
3  a
```

expected result

```
1 2 a a
1 2 b null
```

does not work:

```
select t1.id,t2.id, t1.f1,t2.f1
from table t1
left join table t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1 and t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to do a recursive self-join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757260/simplest-way-to-do-a-recursive-self-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct is a bit strange, but you need to filter on the first table in `where`:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t1.f1, t2.f1
from table t1 left join
     table t2
     on t1.f1 = t2.f1 and t2.id = 2
where t1.id = 1 ;
```

The general rule for a `left join` is that conditions on the first table go in the `where` clause.  Conditions on the second table go in the `on` clause.