# recursive query to fetch user list

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have the table `user` which has `user_name` and `manager` name. I want to get the users who are having ramya as manager and reportee's reportee

**users table**

```
SNO user_name   manager
1    vani        Ramya
2    ramya       geetha
3    priya       ramya
4    mani        ramya
5    latha       vani
6.   hema        Anitha 
7.   kavitha     latha
8    Mala        kavitha
```

I want to get the name ramya and ramya's reportee vani,priya and mani and get latha who is having vani as manager who is having ramya as manager.

I want to get

```
ramya,
vani,
priya,
mani,
latha,
kavitha,
mala
```

and so it if mala have any reportee.

I'm trying this for Laravel query

```
create table users (user_name  varchar(50), manager varchar(50));

insert into users(user_name,manager) values ('vani','Ramya'),('ramya','geetha'),('priya','ramya'),('mani','ramya'),('latha','vani'),('hema','Anitha'),('kavitha','latha'),('Mala','Kavitha')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39a98e/1

```
select a.user_name from 
users a left join users b
on a.manager=b.user_name
where a.user_name='Ramya' or a.manager='ramya' or b.manager='Ramya'
```

now caught only ramya,vani,priya,mani,latha

Comment: How many levels back do you want to look?

Comment: infinite,atleast  15 interation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to do a recursive self-join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757260/simplest-way-to-do-a-recursive-self-join)